# My django keeps saying my posts are published at night

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.9 and when I create a post the publish date will say some thing like this

```
March 25, 2016, midnight
```

and in my models.py I have this

```
 publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

before that I had it like this

```
 publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

they both say midnight. How do I make the time display correclty

in my settings.py

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: Where are you looking at the publish date?

Answer (score 0):

with:

publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_time_add = True)

your field set the time automatic when the object is created for first time.

and with auto_time_now the field value change everytime you change the model.

look this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#datefield

I dont have a good english but i hope that help to you. :)

Comment: This is useful, but not what the person wants.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

if `auto_now = True`, the DateTimeField will be recorded whenever it saves and updates,

elif `auto_now_add = True`, the DateTimeField will be recorded whenever it creates.